# How do I get my the bottom position of tooltip to appear over my link, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am working on a dynamic tooltip...I'm stuck on how I can get the bottom position of `#MyAuction-BidHistory` to appear just above my link `a.my-auction-history`?

Here is my code so far:

```
var linkOffset = $('a.my-auction-history').offset().top;    

$('.my-auction-history').mouseover(function(e){     
    $.get('/auction/includes/new-bidhistory.asp?lplateid=' + pListedPlatesId + "&xx=" + t, function(data){ 
        $('#MyAuction-BidHistory').css({'display':'block', 'opacity':'0', 'top':linkOffset }).animate({opacity:1}, 200).html(data); 
    });
});
```

I only need to work out the Y co-ordinates as `#MyAuction-BidHistory` has been `position:absolute;` & has `margin-left:300px;`

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: If you have jQuery UI you could you the position tool from that.

Comment: @Nalum - Sorry, I'm not using JQuery UI...I'm a beginner at JQuery & need as much practice as possible, anyway thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `$('a.my-auction-history').offset().top`? It should give you the position of the `<a>` element relative to the parent *box*, i.e. the ancestor element with `position: absolute|relative|fixed`, or simply the `<body>`.

Comment: OK Great...some progress. Although the my tooltip doesnt move to each link in my table?... I've updated the question with the revised code. Thanks

Comment: Ok, it seems that `.my-auction-history` is collection of elements? replace `top: linkOffset` with `top: $(this).offset().top` to find out the actual `top` value of the element that is firing `mouseover`.

Comment: I tried changing my code as advised, but now the tooltip doesnt appear?

Comment: @Nasir Are you using any dev tools like FireBug? Try to probe the value to see if it's correct instead of endlessly observe the behavior. I don't have any answer if all I have was "the tooltip doesn't appear".

Comment: here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/mvXDV/11/ ...its gets data from the server and loads it into #MyAuction-BidHistory

Answer (score 0):

Get `a.my-auction-history` position relative to the document with [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)
and its dimensions with [.height() and .width()](http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/)

now you have all you need to absolute position the tooltip relative to the document